# Google API certificate issue via Restful Adapter

Tags: gmail-api

We are facing a SSL certificate issue while executing Token create Interface from SAP side.
For that while troubleshooting we got new 3 SSL certificates from SAP chain verifier, for this please find attached screenshot.

We downloaded those certificates and found out that the Root certificate is not trusted, also the intermediate certificate is different as per chain verifier. We are attaching all certificates in the zip file, please check.

If possible can you please provide a valid SSL certificate for Google token create API. So we can resolve this issue.